# Default folder in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I have categorised the latex documents in my Overleaf account into various folders such as: 'work', 'personal', 'studies', 'uncategorised'.

Whenever I log in to the account, the last folder I had been working is selected. I'd like my Overleaf to always open to the 'uncategorised' folder.

Is there any way to open the default folder every time I log in / refresh Overleaf?

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Not currently, the project list will open to the last view you had selected. In the future, you can use overleaf.com/contact for Overleaf-specific questions.

Comment: Thanks @PaulGessler. You can put that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this from [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620531/default-folder-in-overleaf#comment1549368_620531), for the sake of completeness.

What you want to achieve is not possible as of Oct 28, 2021.
The project list will open to the last view you had selected. In the future, you can use overleaf.com/contact for Overleaf-specific questions.